# Algebraic Disproof $n^2+n+41$

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, integers

The statement "$n^2+n+41$ is a prime number for all positive integers 'n'." is false. I can disprove it by using n=40 (proof by conjecture) however how would I go about proving this algebraically?

Comment: If n is any multiple of 41, it won't be prime because it will be divisible by 41, surely?

Comment: n isn't necessarily a multiple of 41...

Comment: I'd encourage you to read your question, read my answer, and then think for a bit before writing a further reply.

Comment: @BenHughes not *always* a multiple of $41$, but it *will occasionally be* a multiple of $41$.  All we need is at least one example of an $n$ for which $n^2+n+41$ is not prime to disprove the statement "$n^2+n+41$ is always prime."  Matt is pointing out that any $n$ which happens to be a multiple of $41$ will trivially have $41$ as a factor of $n^2+n+41$.

Comment: @BenHughes Have you read carefully Matt S comment? It disproves the statement "All $p=n^2+n+41$ are primes because if you take $n=41$ then $p$ is composite.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ be a non-constant integer polynomial and an integer $x$. Suppose that prime $p$ divides $P(x)$.

We conclude $p$ divides $P(x+pk)$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z$.

Since the values $p,0$ and $-p$ are taken finitely many times we conclude $P(x+pk)$ is not prime for almost all values of $k$.

This works for any polynomial, not just $n^2+n+41$

Answer (score 2):

Another class of $n$ for which $n^2 + n + 41$ is composite: $n = 40 + m^2$ for integer $m$, as then $n^2 + n + 41 = (m^2 + m + 41)(m^2 - m + 41)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n=40$. The expression would then be $40^2+40+41$. Spoiler alert, this equals $41^2$ which obviously isn't prime. But how do we know that without actually calculating it? Lets take the expression $(n+1)(n+1)$. This should give us $(n+1)$ squared. If we multiply this polynomial out, we get $n^2+2n+1$. Lets focus on the $2n+1$. We can rewrite the expression to be $n + (n + 1)$. So just by doing some simple algebra and playing around with the numbers, we can now prove that consecutive perfect squares have a difference of the square root of the first square plus the square root of the second square.

Some examples: 
$4^2=3^2+3+4$ , 
$5^2=4^2+4+5$ , 
$6^2=5^2+5+6$

So whenever you have $n^2+n+(n+1)$, the answer will be a perfect square, specifically, $(n+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$n^2 +n+41 = n(n+1) +41$;

Let

1)$n=41k$, then

$41k(41k+1) +41 = $

$41×(k(41k+1) +1)$ , not prime.

2)$ n+1=41k,$ then

$(41k-1)41k +41 =$

$ 41× (k(41k-1) +1),$ not prime.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n^2+n+41=p$ and consider $m=p+n$ we have that $$m^2+m+41=p^2+2pn+n^2+p+n+41=p^2+2pn+2p=p(p+2n+2)$$

So if $n\ge 0$ this is not prime. Note that this does not depend on $p$ being prime.

Comment: I’m unsure where you’ve got “m” from. What is m=p+n?

Comment: @BenHughes I have taken a pair $n, p$ related by the equation $n^2+n+41=p$ - so I can choose $n$, and derive $p$ from that. Then simply $m=n+p=n^2+2n+41$